# Formatting a new disk partition

Tags: windows-server-2008, partition, hard-drive, gpt, mbr

I just added a new raid1 volume to my Windows 2008 server.

The raid sync has just completed so I want to format it.

I got this message:

[image]

That disk will be used just for storage, no need to boot anything from it.
Can I just cancel this dialog and allocate a partition as always or do I have to choose?

In the second case... what is better? The disk is 500GB and system isn't Itanium based. So MBR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is disk partitioning style. If you want later to use multiple partitons on disk, so is better to use gpt, becouse of mbr limits (it supports only 4 partition table entries and you may need to use secondary structure named extended in that case). Also, mbr have limit of partition size (2Tb).

In windows i think is no original way to use such volume without mbr/gpt. Only removable media without either GPT or MBR formatting is considered a "superfloppy." The entire media is treated as a single partition. Hard disk drives on external buses such as SCSI or IEEE 1394 are not considered removable.

Answer (score 0):

You want to initialise that new volume and if it's just going to be used for data I'd used GPT on it in case you ever want to expand it you would fine that option more flexible.